# Form can not be validated in .NET Core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, unobtrusive-validation

```
    <form id="formElem">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <input asp-for="ID" type="hidden" />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" required class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label"></label>
                <textarea asp-for="Description" required rows="5" class="form-control"></textarea>
                <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ImageData" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ImageData" type="file" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ImageData" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>




    <div class="form-group  col-sm-3">
        <input type="submit" id="dataSend" name="btn" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>
```

JS:

```
        $("#dataSend").on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('ImageData', $('#ImageData')[0].files[0]);

        formData.append('ID', document.getElementById('ID').value);
        formData.append('Name', document.getElementById('Name').value);
        formData.append('Description', document.getElementById('Description').value);
        formData.append('btn', 'Save');

        $.ajax({
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Products/AddProduct',
            data: formData,
            success: function (response) {

                window.location.href = "/Products/Index";
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log("error.");
            },
        });
    });
```

When I click on the save button, it directly calls the `AddProduct` action, though all form fields are blank. My question is, why my model is not validated, despite there is a `[Required]` Annotation on the `Name` and `Description` fields in the model class. This happens when I use JavaScript.

Also, I used `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js` and `jquery.validate.min.js` files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`e.preventDefault();` will prevent the form validation as well. To check for validation without submitting a form use `valid()`. In case of error as `$("#formElem").valid() is not a function.`, check if `jquery.validate.min.js` is included.

As

```
$("#dataSend").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $("#formElem").valid();
    ...
```

Further in your AddProduct method, have you checked for the Model state? Such as

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
   {
     //Don't add product
     // return page();
  }
```

Comment: thanks Sayyed Validation work but after fill all fields form not submitted its give me error checkValidity is not property

Comment: @Abdulaziz for jQuery we have to use `valid()` method. I have updated the answer, if you receive an error as `$("#formElem").valid() is not a function.` then include `jquery.validate.min.js`